# How to use qemu to start macOS virtual machine?

Tags: boot, virtual-machine, qemu, macos

I tried

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -accel hvf \
    -cpu host \
    -smp 4 \
    -m 8G \
    -vga virtio \
    -display default,show-cursor=on \
    -device virtio-net,netdev=vmnic -netdev user,id=vmnic \
    -audiodev coreaudio,id=coreaudio \
    -device ich9-intel-hda -device hda-output,audiodev=coreaudio \
    -cdrom ~/Desktop/Monterey.iso \
    -drive file=montereygpuless.qcow2,if=virtio
```

But I get a "No bootable device" error. What should I do to run macOS on a qemu virtual machine?

Comment: I suppose you know that Apple did introduce a couple of mechanisms to prevent running MacOS on other hardware, including emulations? Did you try to follow any guideline how to circumvent these obstacles?

Comment: @Philippos I can't find any, all the guides I've found are how to run macOS in qemu kvm on linux or in proxmox, but I have macOS host OS